# physics for top-down racing game help - Flash / AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, game-physics

I am trying to figure out the collision physics for a top-down racing game in Flash / AS3.  I am currently using the hitTestPoint method for detecting collisions, but I don't know how to apply a decent physics method to bounce a vehicle off of a wall that it hits.  Does anyone have any ideas or perhaps be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you need: [Emanuele Feronato - CREATE A FLASH RACING GAME TUTORIAL (AS3 VERSION)](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/06/16/create-a-flash-racing-game-tutorial-as3-version/). Might what to check out the AS2 version for a bit more detail.

Comment: When I use his implementation, any time I adjust the speed the car will drive through the barriers and behave erratically.  It's a great idea, but doesn't work well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to figure out what to do, to get started with game programming, then TandemAdam's link seems like a great place to start.

If you need something a bit more involved, then I suggest you plug into someone else's physics engine:
http://box2dflash.sourceforge.net/

If you want something in-between, and are willing to dive into learning a lot about basic game physics, then see this tutorial:
http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique.html
(note, the link seems to be down for me, right now, but that might just be my work's proxy.  Google cache is still picking it up)